# Code a search on my tapestry website?

Tags: java, search, full-text-search, search-engine, tapestry

What is the best way to code a search for my website developed in tapestry?

I have the following code in my layout.tml:

```
<div id="search" > 
  <form method="get" action="#"> 
<div> 
  <input type="text" name="s" id="search-text" value="" /> 
  <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="GO" /> 
</div> 
  </form>
```

I am just unsure of how to actually implement the search.
If anyone can help or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to create a search engine depends completely on what type of site you have.

If you've got a blog or other collection of articles that are accessible to anyone you could simply add [Google SiteSearch](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/) and let Google index your site.

If you've got a product database with titles/descriptions, you should probably go for [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/). If you're already using Hibernate, it's easy to use Lucene through [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) (there's also [book](http://www.manning.com/bernard/)).

Comment: it also has nothing to do with choice of front-end technology (I don't understand how/why Tapestry fits into this)

Answer (score 0):

You need to index the content and keywords in some database and then fire SQL queries on it the smart way. That's going to be **a lot** of work to get it decently to work. Given the skillset shown as far by you, I would rather recommend to just use a 3rd party search API for this, such as [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/). Alternatively you can also just use [Google Sitesearch](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/).